# Android Resource Linking Failed (Can't find anything on Google that fixes this specifically)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been having the most difficult time to simply run the Google Maps API in Android Studio. I have managed to navigate through most of the errors except this one.

[image: Error for this project]

This last bit that comes at the end is

```
Command: C:\Users\fdher\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\5d744ebf759552512dd49d47a67bee49\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
    C:\Users\fdher\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
    --manifest\
    C:\Users\fdher\AndroidStudioProjects\FUSARTOURLIFE2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\resources\AndroidManifest.xml\
    -o\
    C:\Users\fdher\AndroidStudioProjects\FUSARTOURLIFE2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
    -R\
    @C:\Users\fdher\AndroidStudioProjects\FUSARTOURLIFE2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
    --auto-add-overlay\
    --java\
    C:\Users\fdher\AndroidStudioProjects\FUSARTOURLIFE2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
    --custom-package\
    com.example.fdher.fusartourlife\
    -0\
    apk\
    --preferred-density\
    420dpi\
    --output-text-symbols\
    C:\Users\fdher\AndroidStudioProjects\FUSARTOURLIFE2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
    --no-version-vectors
          Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

This is what my manifest file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.fdher.fusartourlife">

<user-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<user-permission android:name = 
 "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<user_permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCFkMk9O7iiPVtrMorVPUTptkv8KCGsPgs"/>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

The manifest has two identical errors that are for .MapActivity and .MainActivity

[image: Manifest bug]

I have just started using Android Studio so if I missed something blatantly obvious please be kind. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Added both build.gradle files

```
app build.gradle 

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fdher.fusartourlife"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
   layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

 }
```

And the one outside of the app FUSTOURLIFE build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
 all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
        // belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
         jcenter()
    }
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

This is my string.xml file

```
     <resources>
     <string 
 name="google_maps_API_key">API_KEY</string>
     <string name="app_name">FUSARTOURLIFE</string>
 </resources>
```

This is my colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
     <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
     <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
 </resources>
```

This is the styles.xml file

```
<resources>

     <!-- Base application theme. -->
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
         <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
     </style>

 </resources>
```

EDIT: ANSWER------------------------------------

Add the below line in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: post your build.gradle file.

Comment: Thank you, I added it @nupadhyaya

Comment: For the first error I think you need to add a dependency on app compat to your build.gradle. As for the other ones, could you post the contents of all of the files under `src/main/res/values/<name>.xml`?

Comment: What would that app dependency look like in code form? And I added those three.   @IzabelaOrlowska

Comment: for example "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'"

Comment: I ran that implementation and its giving me an error saying some library is still 26.1.0 and so it won't run because of the incompatibility...Any idea what other library would still be running that? It doesn't give me a path and I've searched and can't really find what it's asking

Comment: Meawhile i think you shouldn't post your API_KEY. Just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The style Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and the missing colors are from AppCompat library. Add the dependency on it in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Make sure the version of the library matches your compile SDK value.

Comment: My target and compile are 28 but whenever I run it it says some library is still 26.1.0 and so it won't run...Any idea what other library would still be running that? It doesn't give me a path and I've searched and can't really find what it's asking...

Comment: You can run "gradlew app:dependencies" to see what depends on what and which versions.

Answer (score 0):

For initial setup and see how to configure google maps, start android studio and select Google Maps activity which will do all these configurations automatically.

Comment: That also created a myriad of errors upon running so I just followed the instructions on the website on how to make it from scratch thinking it would be better...

Comment: did you manage to make it work?
if Google maps from android studio is not working then may be your SDK is not updated.

Comment: No I did not. Everything is up to date

Comment: In your gradle. change targetSdkVersion28 and CompileSdkVersion28 also. It'll work